# Plotting lines over an image using the same projection

Tags: python, image, matplotlib, astronomy, astropy

I want to make a plot using .fits files (astronomical images) and I am experiencing two issues which I think they are related:

Using this example from astropy:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from astropy.io import fits
from astropy.wcs import WCS
from astropy.utils.data import download_file

fits_file = 'http://data.astropy.org/tutorials/FITS-images/HorseHead.fits'
image_file = download_file(fits_file, cache=True)
hdu = fits.open(image_file)[0]
wcs = WCS(hdu.header)

fig = plt.figure()
fig.add_subplot(111, projection=wcs)
plt.imshow(hdu.data, origin='lower', cmap='cubehelix')
plt.xlabel('RA')
plt.ylabel('Dec')
plt.show()
```

I can generate this image:

[image]

Now I would like to plot some points using the same coordinates as the image:

```
plt.scatter(85, -2, color='red')
```

However, when I do this:

[image]

I am ploting at the pixel coordinantes. Furthermore, the image no longer matches the frame size (although the coordinates seem fine)

Any advice on how to deal with these issues?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is very easy to plot given coordinates. All you have to do is apply a [`transform`](http://wcsaxes.readthedocs.io/en/latest/overlays.html#world-coordinates).

I copied your example and added comments where I changed something and why.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from astropy.io import fits
from astropy.wcs import WCS
from astropy.utils.data import download_file

fits_file = 'http://data.astropy.org/tutorials/FITS-images/HorseHead.fits'
image_file = download_file(fits_file, cache=True)

# Note that it's better to open the file with a context manager so no
# file handle is accidentally left open.
with fits.open(image_file) as hdus:
    img = hdus[0].data
    wcs = WCS(hdus[0].header)

fig = plt.figure()

# You need to "catch" the axes here so you have access to the transform-function.
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection=wcs)
plt.imshow(img, origin='lower', cmap='cubehelix')
plt.xlabel('RA')
plt.ylabel('Dec')

# Apply a transform-function:
plt.scatter(85, -2, color='red', transform=ax.get_transform('world'))
```

And the result is:

[image]

Note that if you want the Canvas to only show the region of the image just apply the limits again afterwards:

```
# Add a scatter point which is in the extend of the image:
plt.scatter(85.3, -2.5, color='red', transform=ax.get_transform('world'))

plt.ylim(0, img.shape[0])
plt.xlim(0, img.shape[1])
```

which gives:

[image]

A side note as well here. AstroPy has a great units support so instead of converting arcmins and arcsecs to degrees you can just define the "unit". You still need the transform though:

```
from astropy import units as u
x0 = 85 * u.degree + 20 * u.arcmin
y0 = -(2 * u.degree + 25 * u.arcmin)
plt.scatter(x0, y0, color='red', transform=ax.get_transform('world'))
```

[image]

Comment: Wow! Thank you very much for the reply and all the great advice!